# How do I pass a GET parameter to ajax and load the data in a popup?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an html page that contains a table with course links.  When you hover over a link, the information from the course table in the database should display inside of a bootstrap popup or information box and call on ajax so that the information is loaded asynchronously.  I use $(this).attr('href') to pull the contents of the page.  However, it pulls the entire contents of the page and I only want the information within the div.  Here is the contents of my php script:

```
<?

// Display table for IT plan
$submitted = isset($_POST['submit']);

// when form is submitted, include the correct schedule
if ($submitted) {

    $prog = $_POST['program'];
    $qtr = $_POST['quarter'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];

    // if bas program is selected, modify the sched string
    if ($prog == "bas-network" || $prog == "bas-software") {
        $sched = $prog. '-' .$qtr. '-' .$class;
        //echo $sched;
    } else {
        $sched = $prog. '-' .$qtr;
    }

    $path = "schedules/";
    include ($path . $sched .'.html');
}

require 'connect.php';

$id = $_GET['courseid'];
//print_r($_GET);

if ($id) {
    try {
        // Create a new PDO connection object
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jim_grcc', $user, $pass);
        // Set the error mode
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM course WHERE courseid = :id');
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
        // Get array containing all of the result rows
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        // Print data if one of the rows were returned
        if ($row != null  ) {
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<h3>".$row['coursenum']. ": " .$row['title'] . "</h3>";
            echo "<strong>Course number: </strong>" .$row['coursenum'] ."<br><br>";
            echo "<strong>Title: </strong>" .$row['title'] ."<br><br>";
            echo "<strong>Description: </strong>" .$row['description'] ."<br><br>";
            echo "<strong>Credits: </strong>" .$row['credits'] ."<br><br>";
            echo "<strong>Prerequisites:</strong> " .$row['prereqs'] ."";
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo "No rows returned";
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
}
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table a").hover(function() { 
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.get(href, function( data ) {
                alert(data);
        }); 
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is how the table is set up:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it114">IT 114</a></td>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it131">IT 131</a></td>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it135">IT 135</a></td>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it190">IT 190</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it141">IT 141</a></td>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it160">IT 160</a></td>
    <td><a href="../it-advising/programs-process.php?courseid=it201">IT 201</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I am using GET parameters since the courseid is passed through the link.  An example of the query string would be: programs-process.php?courseid=it190.  I thought I might be able to pass id as a data parameter in $.get, but the console is showing null or undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate PHP file that only send those information based on a value you pass to it. You send an identifier variable to the file and let it return the data you need.

The reason why you are getting the whole page is most likely you have HMTL markup in the file you are using.